# Extracting Content-Type of external website and save the value on JSON file as "Null"

Tags: php, json, null

I'm trying to extract the encode of external website and save it on a JSON File (UTF-8).

It was working well until I tried "www.secra.de" it save the value from this page as Null.

As I can see is that obtain more than values on the "Content-Type" and I think it could be the redirection but I'm not sure.

**What is the best way to solve it?**

```
    $domain   = "http://www.secra.de";
    $info = get_headers($domain, 1)["Content-Type"];
    $infostr = explode('=', $info);
    $encoding = end($infostr);

    if (!empty($info)){
        $data_array[$key]['encode'] = $encoding;
    } else {
        $data_array[$key]['encode'] = "It don't have Encode";
    }
    $json = json_encode($data_array);
    file_put_contents('data/data.json', $json);
};
```

Comment: What exactly is the value of `$info` that doesn't work…?

Comment: $info is working, I did some "tests" and the problem is $infostr = explode('=', $info); I think, if I print $info, it show values of all Content-Type but if I print $encoding it shows "Null"

Comment: So, I repeat, what is the specific value of `$info` when it doesn't work? If you replace `$info` with `'text/html; charset=utf-8'`, then your code works fine.

Comment: It is the value: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 [1] => text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: Wat? Where exactly did you get that value from?

Comment: I get it with this: $info = get_headers($domain, 1)["Content-Type"];
    print_r($info);
    exit;

Comment: 1) Can't reproduce. 2) The result of that should still not be `null`.

Comment: I changed the code of my post, now you can reproduce it I think

Comment: On www.google.com it works but on www.gmail.com it shows null too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `http://www.secra.de` redirects to `https://www.secra.de`, and the `get_headers` functions returns you the Content-Type for *both* the original and the redirected request:

```
[Content-Type] => Array
    (
        [0] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
        [1] => text/html; charset=utf-8
    )
```

So the problem is that you're treating `$info` as a string when it is an array. Fix that:

```
$info = get_headers($domain, 1)["Content-Type"];
if (is_array($info)) {
    $info = end($info);
}
$infostr = explode('=', $info);
$encoding = end($infostr);
```

Comment: One question, can you explain me this line of your code? if (is_array($info)) {
    $info = end($info);
}